# Jetpack compose LazyColumn key recompose problem?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, key, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

My app(jetpack compose) can reorder list's items by drag and drop.

if user reorder(drag) Trip1 to up, `showingTripList` will be like this : [0, 1, 2, 3] -> [1, 0, 2, 3]

and then, user reorder Trip2 to up, Log will be like this

```
[update slide state] showingTripList: [0, 1, 2, 3] - 1 DOWN
```

It's not what I want. I want [1, 0, 2, 3].

[gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqpaE.gif)

As you can see on gif, if `showingTripList` is [1, 0, 2, 3], Trip 0 will be go down.

But Trip 1 go down. Because `showingTripList` is [0, 1, 2, 3]

```
@Entity(tableName = "trips")
data class Trip(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0,
    var orderId: Int = 0,
    val dateList: List<Date> = listOf(),
    //...
): Cloneable {
    public override fun clone(): Trip{
        return Trip(
            id, orderId, dateList.map{ it.clone() }
        )
    }

    //...
}
```

```
data class AppUiState(
    val tripList: List<Trip>? = null,
    val tempTripList: List<Trip>? = null
)

class AppViewModel(
    private val tripsRepository: TripRepository,
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _appUiState = MutableStateFlow(AppUiState())
    val appUiState = _appUiState.asStateFlow()

    //is load repository done
    private val _isReady = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isReady = _isReady.asStateFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            updateAppUiStateFromRepository()
        }

        viewModelScope.launch {
            while (!_isReady.value) {
                if (_appUiState.value.tripList != null) {
                    updateUiState(true, _appUiState.value.tripList)
                    _isReady.value = true
                }
                delay(100)
            }
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

```
val appUiState by appViewModel.appUiState.collectAsState()
val originalTripList: List<Trip> = appUiState.tripList ?: listOf()
val tempTripList: List<Trip> = appUiState.tempTripList ?: listOf()


val showingTripList =
    if (isEditMode) tempTripList
    else            originalTripList



LazyColumn(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp, 8.dp, 16.dp, 200.dp),
    modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
) {
    if (showingTripList.isNotEmpty()) {
        items(showingTripList){ trip ->

            //each trip item
            key(trip){
                val slideState = slideStates[trip.id] ?: SlideState.NONE

                TripListItem(
                    trip = trip,
                    tripList = showingTripList,
                    isEditMode = isEditMode,
                    onTripClick = { trip ->
                        navigateToTrip(false, trip)
                    },
                    slideState = slideState,
                    updateSlideState = { tripIdx_, slideState_ ->
                        //this - showingTripList is before data <---------------------------
                        Log.d("test", "[update slide state] showingTripList: ${showingTripList.map { it.titleText }} - ${showingTripList[tripIdx_].titleText} $slideState_")
                        slideStates[showingTripList[tripIdx_].id] = slideState_
                    },
                    updateItemPosition = { currentIndex_, destinationIndex_ ->
                        //at on drag end
                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            //showingTripList: [0, 1, 2, 3] -> [1, 0, 2, 3]
                            //update appViewModel tempTripList
                            appViewModel.reorderTempTripList(currentIndex_, destinationIndex_)
                        }

                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            slideStates.putAll(showingTripList.map { trip -> trip.id }.associateWith { SlideState.NONE })
                        }
                    }
                )
            }

            MySpacerColumn(height = 16.dp)
        }
    }
}
```

I want `showingTripList` to [1, 0, 2, 3]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I just added an answer to your question below. Please let me know if this resolves your issue. If it does, you can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left ot the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following part of the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#item-keys):

> However, there is one limitation on what types you can use as item
> keys. The key's type must be supported by Bundle, Android’s mechanism
> for keeping the states when the Activity is recreated. Bundle supports
> types like primitives, enums or Parcelables.

My guess is that your `trip` value is a Kotlin object, which in itself is not a supported data type for the [Android Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle).

So instead provide a unique primitive field within your `trip` object as an ID, for example as follows:

```
key(trip.id){  // each trip has an "id" field with a unique number
    //...
}
```

As a small side note, you could also use the keys attribute provided by the items() function like this:

```
items(
    items = showingTripList,
    key = { trip -> trip.id }
) { trip ->

    //each trip item
    val slideState = slideStates[trip.id] ?: SlideState.NONE
    // ...
)
```

Comment: It doesen't work... And I add some code